# [iOS]Layer on UILabel, why is not full?

Tags: ios, uilabel, calayer

I custom a BWLabel to draw the label's border.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    UIBezierPath *linePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [linePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(frame.size.width, 0)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, frame.size.height)];

    CAShapeLayer *lineLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    lineLayer.lineWidth = 3.0f;
    lineLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    lineLayer.path = linePath.CGPath;

    [self.layer addSublayer:lineLayer];
}
```

I use Debug View Hierarchy to see the BWLabel.
[image]

I have a question, why the CAShapeLayer is not full?

Comment: add [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)]; also

Comment: Have you checked on device? I mean i can be issue with the layout

Comment: not about layout,u can try~

Answer (score 0):

your draw rect should look like this

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
     CGRect frame = self.frame;
    UIBezierPath *linePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [linePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(frame.size.width, 0)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, frame.size.height)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

    CAShapeLayer *lineLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    lineLayer.lineWidth = 3.0f;
    lineLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    lineLayer.path = linePath.CGPath;

    [self.layer addSublayer:lineLayer];    
}
```

Comment: I not mean the full border. just mean the layer is not full on label when i use the Simulator